# How to find any Django classes' import path

Tags: django

I feel really dumb having to ask this question, but I often find a class I want to use in Django and have a tough time figuring out what its import path is.  I end up clicking google result after google result until someone happens to include its path in a question, answer, or comment.  Sometimes it's easy and other times it's tough.

For example, I was investigating an exception I was seeing about atomic transactions in my unit tests and I learned about a class I wanted to try called `TransactionTestCase`.  My first stop was the [Django documentation on the class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/testing/tools/#transactiontestcase).  You would think that the first thing in the documentation on that class would be where it lives and how to import it, but it's not in the documentation on that page about that class.

What does everyone else do?  Does there exist a 1-step reliable means of looking up any class's import path?  Or does everyone just know it by inference or from reading the paragraphs of documentation and meandering through links in the documentation or use a heuristic by chopping up and searching on components of the camelcase name?  What am I missing here?  I'm sure I'll be embarrassed by the answer, but I'm tired of indeterminate searching.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Django github.

For example:

I searched the https://github.com/django repository for `TransactionTestCase` and found where the class lives in the code. In this case the path is django/test. It is now known that in my code I could write `from django.test import TransactionTestCase`

Below is a screenshot django project path on Github:

[image: github screen shot of django path]

Comment: I don't know how you got to where you took the screenshot, but it's an decent method. It's still non-determinant IMO. When I tried it and clicked on the code results, you still have to scroll through the results to get the import path and look in random places. E.g. the first result I see is `tests/test_utils/test_transactiontestcase.py`, but the import happens to be in the preview of the matches.

Comment: True, sometimes you have to really dig to find it.

Comment: It just shocks me that there exists no lookup. I'm glad it's not just me. The majority of my career, I worked mostly in perl, and on cpan, you can't not find an import path. The vagary comes from which version perl sees first, in which case I just look in `@INC`. Is there some way to programmatically search python's modules? Like, I often `git grep "whatever"` in my codebase to find something. I could like `git grep "class TransactionTestCase"`...